# After retrieving data using query, how to update the data back to the database?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").whereEqualTo("VendorName",Vendorname);
int finalMonth = month;
query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : value)
        {
            String monthCounter = doc.getString("monthCounter");
            Log.d("monthCounter",monthCounter);




            if(finalMonth == 1){
                monthCounter = monthCounter+1;
                doc.getDocumentReference("monthCounter").update("monthCounter",monthCounter);
```

On the line `String monthCounter = doc.getString("monthCounter")` the data has been retrieve successfully. But at below, i am trying to update the data back to the database and i failed to. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: I had try using DocumentReference, but i cannot use whereEqualTo, it need to update the monthCounter where the Database is matched with the VendorName

Comment: So to understand better, do you want to update multiple documents in a qu Please respond with @AlexMamoery or a single one? Is that only a simple +1 increment?

Comment: @AlexMamoery Yes, it will get the month that user chooses, in this case which is january, after user choose january i need the monthCounter to +1 and update into the firestore database

Comment: Does `Log.d("monthCounter",monthCounter);` print something?

Comment: yeap it print 0 because it havent store anything yet

Comment: @AlexMamoery initially the monthCounter it is stored as 0.

Comment: One last question. So you want to increment by one, all user documents, where the "VendorName" field holds some value and the "monthCounter" holds the value of `1`, right?

Comment: In my Firestore database, a Vendor's database consist of the monthCounter, so i am trying to increase the monthCounter by one when the user select a month. (In this case i only show the month January)(FinalMonth = 1)means January. and based on what Vendor the user choose. The VendorName field is to get the Vendor's data that a user selected. I just wanted to allow the monthCounter to increase by one and update the monthCounter into the selected Vendor's database. I hope u understand @AlexMamoery

Comment: To understand better, please provide a screenshot of your db and indicate the exact data you want to filter, and the exact data you increment.

Comment: +1 to Alex's request for a screenshot of the document, as `doc.getString("monthCounter")` makes it seem that you store the count as a string - which would explain why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexMamoery i had upload an image, check above.

Comment: @AlexMamoery I had try to retrieve the monthCounter data by using the query, then now i don't know how to upload to firestore after the monthCounter = monthCounter + 1;

Comment: @AlexMamoery The line doc.getDocumentReference("monthCounter").update("monthCounter",monthCounter); is wrong

Comment: @androidnewbie it looks like you are storing your counters as a string and as FrankvanPuffelen mentioned, it could be the reason why your code doesn't work